# Backlight LED Boost Converter testing

Tags: lcd, boost, led-driver

I am using [LCD](http://file.yizimg.com/4611/2013092616290161.pdf) EJ080NA TFT with LED back-light.

[LM3410](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3410.pdf) is used as backlight driver.

Schematic as below:

[image: LM3410 LED Backlight converter]

But when I am testing it on hardware, I tried without load and with load.
Without load, IC got damaged since boost converter needs load otherwise capacitor gets charge continuously and don't get feedback path for discharge.

If I connect dummy load, R23 value will change as it decides load current. If someone test it without load ( without LCD TFT connector plugged in) each time it will damage LM3410 IC.

**So what is the safest way to test and implement above circuit?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to be rude, but read the freaking manual. You will save yourself and others lots of time.

Let me tell you this, and to anyone who reads this. When you get a new part and datasheet at minimum skim the whole thing, become familiar with it. You should do this before you even consider laying it out on a PCB. I was in the same boat you were a few years back, and then I made sure I read the whole datasheet a few times through. You will get a better more intuitive feel for how the part works. You will have fewer mistakes and a better career. Also if you run into a problem, read the datasheet then look for applications guides. Then if your sure you have the circuit within all circuit guidelines and it still isn't functioning correctly then contact the company. I got lazy the other day and missed an absolute maximum rating, the circuit functioned during functional testing. A company rep caught it, I felt bad.

And I quote:

> OUTPUT OVER-VOLTAGE PROTECTION A simple circuit consisting of an
>   external zener diode can be implemented to protect the output and the
>   LM3410 device from an over-voltage fault condition. If an LED fails
>   open, or is connected backwards, an output open circuit condition will
>   occur. No current is conducted through the LED’s, and the feedback
>   node will equal zero volts. The LM3410 will react to this fault by
>   increasing the duty-cycle, thinking the LED current has dropped. A
>   simple circuit that protects the LM3410 is shown in Figure 18. Zener
>   diode D2 and resistor R3 is placed from VOUT in parallel with the
>   string of LEDs. If the output voltage exceeds the breakdown voltage of
>   the zener diode, current is drawn through the zener diode, R3 and
>   sense resistor R1. Once the voltage across R1 and R3 equals the
>   feedback voltage of 190 mV, the LM3410 will limit its duty-cycle. No
>   damage will occur to the LM3410, the LED’s, or the zener diode. Once
>   the fault is corrected, the application will work as intended.
>   [image]

Comment: I read it in datasheet, i thought about other things which I can do. But, yes .. Thanks !